# Domino 10 upgrade and XPages POI libraries error

Tags: apache-poi, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I upgraded my Domino 9.0.1 to 10 after my databases (used POI import/Export) give POI libraries errors. I'm using Eclipse Update Site database for loading POI. I tested po

**cant load POI libraries:**
[image]

[import java lib are not load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUIcJ.jpg)

**Domino console POI services status:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Target Platform setting in Designer may have been messed up by the V10 upgrade - it's a very-common issue with 9.0.1FP10 and V10. "Fix #1" here may be what you need: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/058650E080E352178525832B00519D2C

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first image shows build errors in Domino Designer. Did you upgrade your Designer to 10 too? If so, then you should reinstall the POI libraries in Designer from your update site.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help Per. Problem resolved for Poi Export actions but Import actions databases continue how to solve library errors [link]https://ibb.co/ydKbqTB [/link]